# Android Live wallpaper preferences not saving

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm trying to save some data when the wallpaper is destroyed, this happens when you rotate the phone for example.

When I step through the code with the debugger the settings seem to save.  However running normally the wallpaper settings do not save.  I destroy the wallpaper by re-installing from the IDE.

In my wallpaper onDestroy() method I do the following:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = m_prefs.edit();
editor.putString(Preferences.INFO_AUTHOR.getParamKey(), currentPhoto.getAuthor());
editor.putString(Preferences.INFO_TAGS.getParamKey(), currentPhoto.getTags());
editor.putString(Preferences.INFO_DESC.getParamKey(), currentPhoto.getDescription());
editor.commit();
```

I've checked at the model currentPhoto is correct at the time of saving.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I have other preferences that are saved at other times and these work fine.

Comment: Firstly, put in some log messages to make sure onDestroy gets called when you're expecting.

Comment: Yeah I've already done that, it definitely gets called! Also I've moved this method to be called every time my data changes, instead on onDestroy() & no problems there.  I'm wondering if its something to do with where the method gets called in the lifecycle.

Comment: Ok, in that case it's very likely indeed Context has been lost already when onDestroy gets called. You could try also use case where you change active wallpaper and see what happens. Updating the whole application is rather unlikely event to happen after all.